# How to replace a string inside a python dictionary using regex

Tags: python, regex

**GOAL**

How to replace a string inside a python dictionary using regex?

**SCRIPT**

```
db_result = cursor.fetchall() # databse

lds_data = {} # dictonary

regex = re.compile(r'^([^: \\]+)')
for lds_item in db_result:
    lds_data.update({re.findall(regex, lds_item[1]) : {'cust_code' : lds_item[0], 'osplatofrm' : lds_item[2]]}})
```

**ERROR - OUTPUT**

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

**DB_RESULT**

```
CODE_CLIENT  HOSTNAME     OSPLATFORM
    1       SRVDATA:23   WINSERVER
```

**FINAL EXPECTED**

```
{SRVDATA : {'CUST_CODE': 1, 'OSPLATFORM': 'WINSERVER'}
```

Comment: `re.findall` returns a **list** which can not be used as a dict key

Comment: `re.findall(regex, lds_item[1])` returns a list, which you then try to set as a key in your dictionary. this fails as dict keys must be immutable objects (strings, ints, etc.)

Comment: How to fix? @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: How to fix?  @Dan

Comment: @LuisV., post `db_result` and the final expected result. What is the goal to use a sequence as a dict key?

Comment: I edited the question @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: can you post the actual value of `db_result` (not it's textual/db representation) ?

Comment: What do you mean, real value? The db_result variable, and an array filled with a select to the database, just can not disclose its actual values because they are the company

Comment: What can I use to help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple approach:

```
# sample DB result (of one record)
db_result = [[1, 'SRVDATA:23', 'WINSERVER']]
lds_data = {}

for lds_item in db_result:
    k = lds_item[1][:lds_item[1].rfind(':')]   # extracting key
    lds_data.update({k: {'cust_code': lds_item[0], 'osplatofrm': lds_item[2]}})

print(lds_data)   # {'SRVDATA': {'cust_code': 1, 'osplatofrm': 'WINSERVER'}}
```